# UFW block dhclient for ipv6

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ufw

I have setup `ufw` and now I'm tring to setup IPv6 using `dhclient`:

```
interface "eth0" {
   send dhcp6.client-id DUID;
}
```

When `ufw` is enabled it blocks dchp for ipv6, when i disable `ufw`, all is OK and `dhcp` starts fine.

`ufw allow from any port 547 to any port 546 proto udp` that help, but is that corect decision?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you share your `ufw` configuration? The question as is it's too broad/vague?

Comment: `ufw allow from any port 547 to any port 546 proto udp` that helps. or that isn't correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your ports *swapped*. If `ufw` is running on the dhcpv6 **server**, you should allow from port `546` to port `547`:

```
sudo ufw allow from any port 546 to any port 547 proto udp
```

Your rule is valid for a dhcpv6 **client**. Please check that `IPv6=yes` is in `/etc/default/ufw`, too. I can't remember if it's enabled by default.

Also, I suggest you configure explicit multicast IPv6 adresses (`fe00::/7`) instead of `any`:

```
sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 546 to fe00::/7 port 547 proto udp
```

If your server is *itself* a DHCPv6 client (i.e. it gets its prefix delegation from a router), you should keep the original rule, too:

```
sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 546 to fe00::/7 port 547 proto udp
sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 547 to fe00::/7 port 546 proto udp
```

Remember, a DHCPv6 Client initiate the connection *from* port `546` to port `547` via a multicast address in the range `fe00::/7`.

Comment: `/etc/default/ufw` `IPv6=yes` but in `uf.conf` there isn't such configuration

Comment: `sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 546 to fe00::/7 port 547 proto udp` i allowed 547 to 546, need vice versa?

Comment: @Beliaf exactly. Server uses port 547 and client 546, i.e. Client initiate the request **from** port 546 **to** port 547.

Comment: ah ok, so i need add 2 rulse `sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 546 to fe00::/7 port 547 proto udp` and `sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 547 to fe00::/7 port 546proto udp` correct?

Comment: cause if i remove `sudo ufw allow from fe00::/7 port 547 to fe00::/7 port 546proto udp` dhcp don't start and i have error `PRC: Depreference scheduled in 1836 seconds.
PRC: Expiration scheduled in 37836 seconds.`

Comment: @Beliaf, you should keep both rules. I'll update my answer to be more specific.